# File is not working correctly in Java

Tags: java, file

So, here's the problem. I'm making a game, and I'm having trouble with the file saving class that saves your progress. It is able to load default values in the file to create a new game, then restarts the game so the changes can take effect. The thing is, the default values are saved, but the game no longer recognizes them. then, when I manually delete the file, the same exact method is used to re-create the file, then the game recognizes it. Here is the class I used:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import mario.simulator.MarioSimulator;

/**
 *
 * @author Jaca
 */
public class filer {
    private static File f;
    private static BufferedReader br;
    private static BufferedWriter bw;
    private boolean docterlicense;
    private boolean driverlicense;
    private boolean policelicense;
    private boolean finishedschool;
    private boolean bullied;
    private boolean messedtubby;
    private boolean toadmode;
    private long candy;
    private long coin;
    private long spaghetti;
    private long cake;
    private long water;
    private long mushroom;
    private long bomb;
    private long gun;
    private int hunger;
    private long respawn;
    private long swag;
    private long awesome;

public filer(){
    f = new File("resource\\config\\save.sav");
    if(!f.exists()){
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            filer.reset();
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            docterlicense = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            policelicense = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            finishedschool = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            driverlicense = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            bullied = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            messedtubby = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            toadmode = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            candy = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            coin = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            spaghetti = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            cake = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            water = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            mushroom = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            bomb = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            gun = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            hunger = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            respawn = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            swag = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            awesome = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            MarioSimulator.loadSave(docterlicense, policelicense, finishedschool, driverlicense, bullied, messedtubby, toadmode,  candy, coin, spaghetti, cake, water, mushroom, bomb, gun, hunger, respawn, swag, awesome);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(filer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

public static void reset(){
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
        bw.write("false");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("false");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("false");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("false");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("false");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("false");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("false");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("0");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("0");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("0");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("0");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("0");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("0");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("0");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("0");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("100");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("0");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("0");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("0");
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(filer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

Any help is helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the game no longer recognises them'?

Comment: Your constructor doesn't do anything if the file exists.

Comment: I'm fairly confident `File` is working correctly in Java. As for *your* program, I'm also confident that it is not working correctly. Finally, for *help* - use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you're ignoring the save file if it exists...

```
f = new File("resource\\config\\save.sav");
if(!f.exists()){
    //...
} // And then what??
```

Instead, you should `reset` the file and THEN load it anyway...

```
f = new File("resource\\config\\save.sav");
if(!f.exists()){
    filer.reset();
}
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
    // Load the file...
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(filer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Make sure you are managing your readers and make the best effort to ensure they are closed appropriately, remember, if you create, you should close it.

If you're using Java 7+ you can use [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as demonstrated above, otherwise you should have a `finally` clause which closes and resources you might have opended (each will probably need there own `try-catch`)

Comment: Yes, very helpful! That was my intention, but I guess I put the read scripts in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0):

I see what I did. The program only reads the file if it doesn't exist! That was just me not paying attention to my code. Maybe, debugging it would be easier if I organize everything a little better, like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import mario.simulator.MarioSimulator;

/**
 *
 * @author Jaca
 */
public class filer {
    private static File f;
    private static BufferedReader br;
    private static BufferedWriter bw;
    private boolean docterlicense;
    private boolean driverlicense;
    private boolean policelicense;
    private boolean finishedschool;
    private boolean bullied;
    private boolean messedtubby;
    private boolean toadmode;
    private long candy;
    private long coin;
    private long spaghetti;
    private long cake;
    private long water;
    private long mushroom;
    private long bomb;
    private long gun;
    private int hunger;
    private long respawn;
    private long swag;
    private long awesome;

    public filer(){
        f = new File("resource\\config\\save.sav");
        if(!f.exists()){ //creates the file if it does not exist
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
                filer.reset(); //loads default values to new file
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(filer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        this.read(); //reads the file
    }

    public void read(){ //reads the file, then passes variables to game thread
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            docterlicense = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            policelicense = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            finishedschool = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            driverlicense = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            bullied = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            messedtubby = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            toadmode = Boolean.parseBoolean(br.readLine());
            candy = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            coin = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            spaghetti = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            cake = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            water = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            mushroom = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            bomb = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            gun = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            hunger = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            respawn = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            swag = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            awesome = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            MarioSimulator.loadSave(docterlicense, policelicense, finishedschool, driverlicense, bullied, messedtubby, toadmode,  candy, coin, spaghetti, cake, water, mushroom, bomb, gun, hunger, respawn, swag, awesome);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(filer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void reset(){ //loads defaults values
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
            bw.write("false");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("false");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("false");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("false");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("false");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("false");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("false");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("0");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("0");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("0");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("0");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("0");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("0");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("0");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("0");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("100");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("0");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("0");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("0");
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(filer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

It's amazing how badly a little error in the code can greatly mess up a program. For those begginner programmers out there, check your code thoroughly before unintentionally wasting other peoples time, like what I just did. Sorry, everybody!